# jQueryMobile forward navigation works but backwards did not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, navigation

I have the following javascript code:

```
var baseName;

$('#fleetList').live('pagebeforeshow',function(event){
    $('#fleet').children().remove('li');

    $.getJSON('ajax/api.php', { "request" : "listFleet", "hash" : baseAuth, "stuId" : $.urlParam('stuId') }, function (data) {
            if (data.fleet.length>0) {
                $('#fleetBaseName').html(baseName + ' ' + data.baseLocation);
                $.each(data.fleet, function(i,item) {
                    $("#fleet").append('' + item.typ + '');
                });
                $('#fleet').listview('refresh');
            } else {
                alert("Sorry, you have no Fleet listed in that base.");
                $.mobile.changePage("baseList.php");
            }
    });
});
```

That code works, when I open my "fleetList.php" with coming from "baseList.php" very well. 
Then the h3-tag with id="fleetBaseName" is filled with the baseName + data.baseLocation.

When I continue to "bookingList.php" and came back to "fleetList.php", then only the fleet is shown but the heading with "fleetBaseName" is gone. I don't remove it and the h3 tag with id="fleetBaseName" is still in the DOM. But it's not visible any more.

What's the problem with it?

PS: I'm using jqm 1.2.0

Comment: Strange behaviour:
When I add an alert(baseName + ' ' + data.baseLocation); right before $('#fleetBaseName').html(baseName + ' ' + data.baseLocation); then it also works in the backward way when coming back from bookingList.php.

What's the trick?

Comment: When debugging with Firebug in single steps, the headline appears when I'm in the backward-way. But it disappears when running the script at once. ^^